# Getting line by line output from a started process

Tags: c#

I'm trying to retrieve the output lines generated by a process I started, here's the code

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (myData singleJob in e.Argument as List<myData>)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("myCommandLineProgram.exe");
        psi.Arguments = "\"" + singleJob.row + "\"";
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.Start();
        StreamReader sr = p.StandardOutput ;
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null )
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(sr.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine);
                    richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();   

            });
        }

        //StreamReader streamOutput = p.StandardOutput;
        //string content = streamOutput.ReadToEnd();   
        //this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        //{
        //    richTextBox1.AppendText(content + Environment.NewLine);
        //});

        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

While the commented out code is always working (but it doesn't parse line by line), the code above is somehow faulty, indeed some lines fail to appear into the richtextbox and some others are blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't that be something like

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
```

(`line` instead of `sr.ReadLine()`)?

Calling `readLine()` twice will discard every second line.

Also, since you're calling `ReadLine` in the delegate you cannot control when the read occurs. It might be that there were several `ReadLines()` (from the `while` line) in between.

Note, that you should also NOT use the `line` variable: This variable always references the same line variable in the loop, this one might contain new content at the time the `AppendText` is executed. You should introduce a new local variable inside the loop like

```
 while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null )
 {
   var theLine = line;
   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
   {
       richTextBox1.AppendText(theLine + Environment.NewLine);
       richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();   
   });
 }
```

Comment: +1 from me for pointing out the line-theLine relation. I learned something new today.

Answer (score 2):

Just change here instead of `ReadLine()`, put `line`. You have already read the line in your while loop

```
string appendingLine = line;
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
          richTextBox1.AppendText(appendingLine + Environment.NewLine);
          richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();   

});
```

**EDIT:** The answer MartinStettner gave is better one. There may be the case where `line` changes before the delegate is executed, therefore some lines can be lost while others can be repeated. Therefore I will change my answer according to Martin's and I want to point out that he should be the one who will take the credit for this answer.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yes it should in most cases, but MartinStettner is right. In some cases, which I can imagine (slow graphic card or some other), delegate  wont be executed before the new ReadLine() occurs, and the variable line will be changed so he can end up with some lost lines. So this code is not so good as Martin's.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was indeed the problem :)